# backbone-localstorage.js - populating the Store()

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage

I've relatively new to backbone and have quickly realised that url: is not sufficient. I need to use `localStorage`:

I have included the .js file, and can see the Stores being created. However I have an "under the hood" API which is performing all the ajax calls - when the user is online.

I need to be able to populate the collections with models from the underlying API. Anybody tried this or got any pointers that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Probably have a good read through this.

http://amplifyjs.com/api/request/ and
http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/

Essentially unifies where your "data" comes from and can handle situations as you have described.